# Setting Custom ActionBar Title from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

In my Main `FragmentActivity`, I setup my custom `ActionBar` title like this:

```
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_titlebar, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "fonts/capsuula.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    tv.setText(this.getTitle());

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

This works perfect.  However, once I open other `Fragments`, I want the title to change.  I am not sure how to access the Main `Activity` to do this?  In the past, I did this:

```
((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(
            catTitle);
```

Can someone advise on the proper method?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28279341/1651286 should be the accepted answer because of its scalability. because all other approaches are making fragment tied to particular activity, which is not a scalable design, what if the same fragment has to be used with multiple activities, also this is what android framework also recommends.

Comment: Look this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705242/1770868

Answer (score 107, accepted):

**===Update October, 30, 2019===**

Since we have new components such as **ViewModel** and **LiveData**, we can have a different/easier way to update Activity Title from Fragment by using ViewModel and Live Data

Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
            .commitNow()
    }
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.title.observe(this, Observer {
        supportActionBar?.title = it
    })
} }
```

MainFragment

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
companion object {
    fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
}
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
}
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.run {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Throwable("invalid activity")
    viewModel.updateActionBarTitle("Custom Title From Fragment")
} }
```

And MainModelView:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val _title = MutableLiveData<String>()
val title: LiveData<String>
get() = _title
fun updateActionBarTitle(title: String) = _title.postValue(title) }
```

And then you can update the Activity title from Fragment using `viewModel.updateActionBarTitle("Custom Title From Fragment")`

**===Update April, 10, 2015===**

You should use listener to update your action bar title

Fragment:

```
public class UpdateActionBarTitleFragment extends Fragment {
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public UpdateActionBarTitleFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction("Custom Title");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_action_bar_title2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String title);
    }
}
```

And Activity:

```
public class UpdateActionBarTitleActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements UpdateActionBarTitleFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_action_bar_title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: It worked for me! I just used getActionBar().setTitle(title) instead in the activity. Thanks

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for- worked better for me than the chosen answer. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It correctly shows how it should be done: If a fragment wants to communicate with its hosting activity, the communication should always happen through an interface. The fragment provides the interface and the activity implements it! If multiple fragments have to communicate the same way with an activity, write an abstract fragment which provides the interface and then let every fragment inherit from this "base fragment".

Comment: By the way: The onAttach(Activity) method used in this answer is deprecated by this time. Check inside the `onAttach(Context)` method wether the passed host activity implements the required interface (retrieve host activity via `context.getActivity()`) .

Comment: After many years I changed this to the accepted answer because as we know, interfaces are the way fragments and activities need to communicate.

Comment: waht about FragmentActivity i need to use this class

Answer (score 156):

What you're doing is correct. `Fragments` don't have access to the `ActionBar` APIs, so you have to call `getActivity`. Unless your `Fragment` is a static inner class, in which case you should create a `WeakReference` to the parent and call Activity.`getActionBar` from there.

To set the title for your `ActionBar`, while using a custom layout, in your `Fragment` you'll need to call `getActivity().setTitle(YOUR_TITLE)`.

The reason you call `setTitle` is because you're calling `getTitle` as the title of your `ActionBar`. `getTitle` returns the title for that `Activity`.

If you don't want to get call `getTitle`, then you'll need to create a public method that sets the text of your `TextView` in the `Activity` that hosts the `Fragment`.

**In your Activity**:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title){
    YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION_BAR_TITLE.setText(title);
}
```

**In your Fragment**:

```
((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(YOUR_TITLE);
```

**Docs:**

[`Activity.getTitle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getTitle())

[`Activity.setTitle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence))

Also, you don't need to call `this.whatever` in the code you provided, just a tip.

Comment: I try and I can't get it to work.  For what its worth, I posted my `XML` and also removed "this".  No changes...  And no, its not a `static` inner class.

Comment: Wait, what doesn't work? In your OP you don't mention anything *not* working, you only mention wanting to know the "proper" method to set the title in the `ActionBar` from a `Fragment`.

Also, I wasn't offering removing `this.whatever` as a solution to anything, that was only a code formatting tip.

Comment: I think I understand what you're having trouble with and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KickingLettuce, I struggle with this answer for a while until I made it work (that's why I upvoted it, as well as your question) : in my navigation-drawer main activity ( `menu_act` ) I made global "mTitle", and, in a fragment, first I assign a title to "mTitle" ( `( (menu_act) getActivity() ).mTitle = "new_title"` ), and immediately I do `( (menu_act) getActivity() ).restoreActionBar();`. Inside "restoreActionBar()" I have "actionBar.setTitle( mTitle );".

Comment: for me, `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((TextView)toolbar.getChildAt(0)).setText(title);`

Comment: This answer works, but according to the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) it's bad practice. If a fragment wants to communicate with its host activity, let the activity implement an interface provided by the fragment. The fragment can then call the method through the implemented interface. See Frank Nguyen answer. His answer is correct.

Comment: This approach have a problem, what if you have many fragments, each one sets a different title on the actionbar. I think it works good if you always replace with new fragment instances. But what if you just add fragments, instead of replacing? the title wont change when you press back, for my case It wont work. I think there should be a better way to achieve that.

Answer (score 32):

Google examples tend to use this within the fragments.

```
private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}
```

The fragment will belong to an ActionBarActivity and that is where the reference to the actionbar is. This is cleaner because the fragment doesn't need to know exactly what activity it is, it only needs to belong to an activity that implements ActionBarActivity. This makes the fragment more flexible and can be added to multiple activities like they are meant to.

Now, all you need to do in the fragment is.

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

This works well if you have a base fragment that your fragments inherit from instead of the normal fragment class.

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    public ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment.

```
public class YourFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. very nice solution , by this way you can also pass custom view to your action bar.

Comment: With recent updates on Android SDK, instead of ActionBarActivity, you may want to downcast to AppCompatActivity in case you are using v7 backwards compatibility library (which you probably should).

Answer (score 13):

I don't think that the accepted answer is a perfect answer for it. Since all the activities that use

> Toolbar

are extended using

> AppCompatActivity

, the fragments called from it can use the below mentioned code for changing the title.

```
((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: Works perfectly even now. Thx!

Answer (score 11):

A simple Kotlin example

Adapt this to your fragment classes:

```kotlin
    /**
     * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
     *
     * Updates the action bar title when onResume() is called on the fragment,
     * which is called every time you navigate to the fragment
     *
     */

    class MyFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            (requireActivity() as MyMainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "My Fragment!"
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Setting `Activity`’s title from a `Fragment` messes up responsibility levels. `Fragment` is contained within an `Activity`, so this is the `Activity`, which should set its own title according to the type of the `Fragment` for example.

Suppose you have an interface:

```
interface TopLevelFragment
{
    String getTitle();
}
```

The `Fragment`s which can influence the `Activity`’s title then implement this interface. While in the hosting activity you write:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(0, new LoginFragment(), "login").commit();
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    if (fragment instanceof TopLevelFragment)
        setTitle(((TopLevelFragment) fragment).getTitle());
}
```

In this manner `Activity` is always in control what title to use, even if several `TopLevelFragment`s are combined, which is quite possible on a tablet.

Answer (score 5):

In the Fragment we can use like this, It's working fine for me.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("YOUR TITLE");
```

Comment: This does not work when the Toolbar of our activity has a TextView that has the role of the title

Comment: @Simon Because it  has nothing to do with `setTitle()`, it is custom implementation and you have to handle it yourself

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if you are having issues with the code, try putting  `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title)` inside `onResume()` of your fragment instead of `onCreateView(...)` i.e

In *MainActivity.java* :

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

In Fragment:

```
 @Override
 public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Your Title");
 }
```

Comment: This was my problem -- **where** I was setting the title. However, `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("title")` sufficed. In Kotlin, my fragment does `activity!!.title = "title`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
getActivity().setTitle("YOUR_TITLE");
```

Comment: This answer is to change the title of the Activity, the question is about the ActionBar's title instead.

Comment: Thanks @Anisetti! That's just what I did in Fragment class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for setting the ActionBar title from fragments, when using NavigationDrawer. 
This solution uses an Interface so the fragments does not need to reference the parent Activity directly:

1) Create an Interface:

```
public interface ActionBarTitleSetter {
    public void setTitle(String title); 
}
```

2) In the Fragment's **onAttach**, cast the activity to the Interface type and call the SetActivityTitle method:

```
@Override 
public void onAttach(Activity activity) { 
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((ActionBarTitleSetter) activity).setTitle(getString(R.string.title_bubbles_map)); 
}
```

3) In the activity, implement the **ActionBarTitleSetter** interface:

```
@Override 
public void setTitle(String title) { 
    mTitle = title; 
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because all other approaches are making fragment tied to particular activity, which is not a scalable design, also this is what android framework also recommends

Answer (score 2):

Best event for change title `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.general, container,  
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // <-Add this line
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    // If use specific menu
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.path_list_menu, menu);
    // If use specific menu

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Fragment");
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a main activity with many fragments you put in, usually using the navigationDrawer. And you have an array of titles for yours fragments, when you press back, for them to change, put this in the main actity that hold the fragments

```
@Override
     public void onBackPressed() {

    int T=getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if(T==1) { finish();}

    if(T>1) {
        int tr = Integer.parseInt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(T-2).getName());
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[tr]);  super.onBackPressed();
      }

}
```

This assumes that for each fragment you give it a tag, usually somewhere when you add the fragments to the list of navigationDrawer, according to the position pressed on the list. So that position is what i capture on the tag:

```
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(position).commit();
```

Now, the navMenuTitles is something you load on the onCreate

```
 // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
```

The array xml is an array type string resource on strings.xml

```
 <!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
    <string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
        <item>Title one</item>
        <item>Title Two</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Save ur Answer in String[] object and set it OnTabChange() in MainActivity as Belowwww

```
String[] object = {"Fragment1","Fragment2","Fragment3"};

public void OnTabChange(String tabId)
{
int pos =mTabHost.getCurrentTab();     //To get tab position
 actionbar.setTitle(object.get(pos));
}


//Setting in View Pager
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(arg0);
actionbar.setTitle(object.get(pos));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The downside to your approach of casting like so

```
((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(
        catTitle);
```

is that your fragment is no longer reusable outside of MainActivityFragment. If you don't plan to use it outside of that activity, then there's no problem. A better approach would be conditionally set the title depending on the activity. So inside your fragment, you would write:

```
if (getActivity() instanceof ActionBarActivity) {
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Some Title");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using android studio 1.4 stable template provided by google than simple you had to write following code in `onNavigationItemSelected` methode
in which your related fragment calling if condition.

```
 setTitle("YOUR FRAGMENT TITLE");
```

Comment: that's wonderful if you have access to the title directly from the activity...  but if the title is a dynamically set string in the fragment there needs to be communication between the fragment and the activity

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting a very simple solution to set ActionBar Title in either
>   fragment or any activity without any headache.
>
> Just modify the xml where is defined Toolbar as below :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

> 1) If you want to set the actionbar in a fragment then :

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

> For using it from anywhere, you can define a method in the activity

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        toolbarTitle.setText(title);
    }
```

> To call this method in activity, simply call it.

```
setActionBarTitle("Your Title")
```

> To call this method from fragment of the activity, simply call it.

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: Excellent! Using the toolbar_title overrides the fragment title if using Android Navigation Components.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto the selected answer, you may also want to add a second method to your main activity. So you would end up with the following methods in your main activity:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

public void setActionBarTitle(int resourceId) {
    setActionBarTitle(getResources().getString(resourceId);
}
```

This will allow you set the title from both a String variable as well as a resource ID such as `R.id.this_is_a_string` from your strings.xml file. This will also work a little more like how `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` works since it allows you to pass in a resource ID.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways as as outlined above. You can also do this in `onNavigationDrawerSelected()`in your `DrawerActivity`

```
public void setTitle(final String title){
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title)).setText(title);
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    fragment = null;
    String title = null;
    switch(position){

    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        title = "Home";
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        title = ("Find Work");
        break;
    ...
    }
    if (fragment != null){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container,
                fragment).commit();

        //The key is this line
        if (title != null && findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title)!= null ) setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, there was an easy answer (after much digging around) to changing a tab title at runtime:

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.getTabAt(MyTabPos).setText("My New Text");

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ViewPager` (like my case) you can use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(YOURE_TAB_BAR.getTabAt(position).getText());
```

in `onPageSelected` method of your `VIEW_PAGER.addOnPageChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, under `onCreate:`

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And in your fragment activity under `onResume`:

```
getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name_science);
```

*Optional:- if they show warning of null reference*

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).setTitle(R.string.app_name_science);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on Ashish answer with Java

```
private void setUI(){
    mainToolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_messaging, R.id.nav_me)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(navDestinationChange);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

private NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener navDestinationChange = new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        if(R.id.nav_home==destination.getId()){
            destination.setLabel("News");
        }
    }
};
```