# setTitle when Fragment is visible again

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have FragmentA and FragmentB and have a problem with setting the title of my Activity when FragmentA becomes back visible.

Flow

1. FragmentA Visible (not added to the backstack)
2. add FragmentB (added to the backstack)
3. back button pressed, not the default implementation but need to capture it in the Fragment but I do `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Now When FragmentA is back visible, the title of the Activity must be changed again
like, FragmentA title = "A", FragmentB title = "B". But when FragmentA is back visible, the title is still "B" because onResume isn't called in FragmentA. What are my options to always set title to "A" in FragmentA is visible.

Code:

FragmentA

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().setTitle("POI's");       
}
```

FragmentB

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        getActivity().setTitle("POI");
        ...
}
```

Comment: instead of changing Title here you can change Title while replacing Fragment

Comment: @SilentKiller your comment doesn't describe how to set the title back when FragmentB is gone with pressing the back button.

Comment: AFAIK, onResume() should always be called when a fragment/activity becomes visible. Why do you override the Back button functionality? And could you try just for the test to leave the default back button functionality?

Comment: @Francesco you need to change title at onCreateView only for resume fragment

Comment: @helleye tried it with the default back button behaviour but without success. onResume of a Fragment is only called when onResume of the Activity is called. But onResume of the Activity isn't called because I don't leave the Activity.

Comment: Look this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705242/1770868

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tested on a single Activity with two fragment which worked fine. See the below code.

Fragment A : which show the app name

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}
```

Fragment B : which show the app name

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setTitle("fragment B");
}
```

Fragment A to B transaction Code :

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,new FragmentB())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

**Update:**
Need to replace fragment like "`replace(R.id.container,new FragmentB())`" rather than add it to FragmentManager to change title of a activity.

Comment: i added it. Please check.

Comment: I guess that's the problem. I'm using the add instead of the replace. I'll try it out

Comment: yapp .. i tried by "add". It shows same problem you faced.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. I'm going to use replace. Update your answer that you need a replace to make it work (for the others).

Answer (score 4):

try to do this

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("your title");
```

Comment: onResume isn't called again so this make no difference.

Comment: it should be called as it is part of the fragment lifecycle. it will always be called as far as I know

Comment: No, only called when you use replace (FragmentTransaction), not working with the add method of the FragmentTransaction.