# Which function will be called when fragment resume

Tags: java, android, fragment, resume

Which function will be called when the `fragment` resume.

I have read this question here [setTitle when Fragment is visible again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639927/settitle-when-fragment-is-visible-again) , but i must use the `add()` function. What should i do? `onResume` function is not called!

EDIT:
In MainActivity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragmentA).commit();
```

when click a button in fragment A, the fragment B will be show:

```
onClick(View v){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,fragmentB).commit(); 
}
```

And when i press back button, it resume to fragment A, but onResume() function in A is not called.

Comment: you should add code,  otherwise the topic is too broad to explain

Comment: why is the onResume method not called?

It is a life-cycle method which is inherited from the fragment class

Comment: @RamanSB i dont know but when i run code, it is not be called :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding a fragment, and not replacing it, the `onResume()` method will not be called for Fragment A. Fragment A did not went to `onPause()` when you `add` another fragment to the parent container.

Have a look at the Android deverlopers page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Comment: But when i add  fragment B, i cant see fragment A, fragment A is not visible :( I want to know how to handle when fragment B remove and fragment A return.