# In android app Toolbar.setTitle method has no effect – application name is shown as title

Tags: android, toolbar, android-support-library

I'm trying to create simple application using android-support-v7:21 library.
Code snippets:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
        mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("My title");
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar            
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But instead of "My title" on Toolbar %application name% is shown.
Seems like `setTitle` method has no effect.
I would like to show "My title".

**UPD:**
Before, `styles.xml` was:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

So, I thought that actionbar is not used.
I add `NoActionBar` to style parent:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

But the problem is not resolved.

Comment: FWIW, I'm on api level 22, and I had the same issue if calling setTitle *after* calling setSupportActionBar, but it worked if calling setTitle *before*. As described in an answer below, after calling setSupportActionBar, the action bar takes ownership of the toolbar and calls directly on the toolbar might not work. I do realize that in your question you *did* in fact call setTitle before setSupportActionBar, so probably this is something that has changed recently.
In any case, using getSupportActionBar().setTitle works just as well.

Comment: The same query asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560904/setting-custom-actionbar-title-from-fragment/51983004#51983004

Comment: Try it - “How set a title for Activity with ToolBar?” https://link.medium.com/cGVg3zVr0Z

Answer (score 611, accepted):

Found the solution:

Instead of:

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("My title");
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
```

I used:

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

And it works.

Comment: nice one, but makes no sense to work this way and not the other....welcome to android 101

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");` may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: @PratikButani So long as the Toolbar has been set as setSupportActionBar() before calling getSupportActionBar() why might it?

Comment: AndroidStudio giving warning if u use Inspect Code.

Comment: Aha, easily resolved: assert getSupportActionBar() != null;

Comment: For me the first snippet you pasted works but the second doesn't!

Comment: Would you please explain why?

Comment: Guys did you really upvoted @PratikButani comment so many times? If you use style theme without action bar but custom **support toolbar v7** and you forget to call `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)` of course you will get null exeption, but if you called it then just ignore this message. Just read - https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Comment: Setting the title before `setSupportActionBar` now works for me. @user25 agree!

Answer (score 126):

For anyone who needs to set up the title **through the Toolbar** some time after setting the SupportActionBar, read this.

The internal implementation of the support library just checks if the Toolbar has a title (not null) at the moment the SupportActionBar is set up. If there is, then this title will be used instead of the window title. You can then set a dummy title while you load the real title.

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("");
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
```

later...

```
mActionBarToolbar.setTitle(title);
```

Comment: It works, but why this is the way it must be done makes no sense to me. Does anyone have an explanation for why this works?

Comment: @Maxwell It makes sense considering the design of the actionbar/toolbar interaction.  The Activity should display a title, if you provide a toolbar without that title, android assumes you want the traditional Activity title control.

Comment: mActionBarToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)); will ensure there is a good default title while keeping the same magical effect of the answer

Comment: @Bevor it works, just see how many votes this answer has... you just did something wrong

Comment: @user25, it also worked bad for me, it removed a back arrow. Then I found another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40571324/2914140. `this.setTitle("Title")`, where `this` - is a reference to an activity.

Comment: i enhanced this answer for those using a collapsing toolbar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown/57635712#57635712

Answer (score 90):

The above answer is totally true but not working for me.

I solved my problem with the following things.

Actually My XML is like that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/confirm_order_mail_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/confirm_order_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/confirm_order_list_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/confirm_order_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried all the option and after all I just removed `CollapsingToolbarLayout` because of i do not need to use in that particular `XML` So My **Final XML** is like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/confirm_order_mail_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/confirm_order_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/confirm_order_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now you have to use `setTitle()` like above answer:

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.confirm_order_toolbar_layout);            
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");
```

---

Now If you want to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `Toolbar` together then you have to use `setTitle()` of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.confirm_order_mail_layout);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("My Title");
```

May it will helps you. Thank you.

Comment: That makes sense, removing the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` solved the problem

Comment: For me the trick with setting title for CollapsingToolbarLayout works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I change the subtitle with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: Since you toolbar is nested under CollapsingToolbarLayout then it is overridden by collapsing toolbar layout. This works for me.

Comment: Bro you save my life!!!
You must both setSupportActionbar before you use collapsingToolbarLayout.seTitle("Title");

Comment: ... collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("My Title"); worket for me perfectly without to remove the collapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: Helped me a lot... Thanks

Answer (score 46):

Simply you can change any activity name by using

```
Activityname.this.setTitle("Title Name");
```

Comment: Or simply `title = "Title"` in Kotlin or maybe `this.setTitle("Title")` in Java.

Answer (score 35):

Try this, you can define title directly in XML:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:title="some title"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

Comment: The easiest but still i need to custom titles dynamically, if you have any idea

Answer (score 15):

To set the title for each Navbar fragment title

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("title");

    return myView;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this .. this method works for me..!! hope it may help somebody..!!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
 android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
 app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >  

<TextView  
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"  
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:gravity="center"  
   android:singleLine="true"  
   android:text="Toolbar Title"  
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"  
   android:textSize="18sp"  
   android:textStyle="bold" />  

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

To display logo in toolbar try the below snippet.
// Set drawable

```
toolbar.setLogo(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.logo));
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: Thank you Ragu Swaminathan.. I was trying to implement SupportActionBar from appcompact activity to give a title to my activity but unable to do it beacuse i need to extend BaseGameActivity. Then i go for toolbar but title not displayed while running. Your method using textbox inside toolbar is working. Recommend it to people in same situation

Comment: toolbar has a method to set the app logo. check my updated answer

Answer (score 11):

```
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: This answer is a stub and should rather be a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), since short answers like this may be considered low quality. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment. If you don't have enough reputation, read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) on how to contribute if you don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @ascripter it is an answer

Answer (score 8):

Please see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763. Apparently it is supposed to work like that. Once you call the `setSupportActionBar()` method call, it then is the responsibility of the ActionBar delegate to route the call to the correct view.

Comment: What's that Actionbar delegate? Here setTitle() doesn't work for toolbar neither for the support actionbar. The native actionbar is disabled in the theme. What the hell is wrong? If only the source code attachment worked in Android Studio I could trace the problem myself!

Answer (score 7):

It's not just about `.setTitle`

more methods of Support Toolbar (Appcompat v7) in `onCreate` works only with

`getSupportActionBar().method()`

and don't work with `mToolbar.method()`

examples:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("toolbar title");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

though next methods works fine without `getSupportActionBar()` in `onCreate`

```
mToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //
    }
```

Problem only with `onCreate` event, you still can use `mToolbar.setTitle()` later instead of annoying `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()`, for example if you add this in `onCreate` it will work (because it will be executed later, after `onCreate`)

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mToolbar.setTitle("toolbar title");
    }
});
```

I prefer to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/35430590/4548520 than https://stackoverflow.com/a/26506858/4548520 because if you change title many times (in different functions) it's more comfortable to use `mToolbar.setTitle()` than longer `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` one and you don't see annoying notification about null exception like with `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()`

Comment: if you want to change the title many times and and using a collapsing toolbar, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown/57635712#57635712

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who needs to set up the title through the Toolbar some time after setting the SupportActionBar (@sorianiv) **AND** your `Toolbar` is inside a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, read this:

```
mToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//toolbar.setTitle(""); // no need to do this
//mToolbarLayout.setTitle("Title"); // if you need an initial title, do this instead
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Then later,

```
mToolbarLayout.setTitle("New Title");
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried to rename the toolbar from the fragment

It helped me, I hope to help someone else

```
Activity activity = this.getActivity();
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            activity.setTitle("Title");
        }

//toolbar.setTitle("Title"); did not give the same results
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Application title will not show as default title on every activity, you can insert different title on every activity. On your activity file bellow the onCreate just paste a single line to set title,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Your Title Here");
```

Just change the text "Your Title Here" to your text.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this in your adapter,
Where MainActivity is your AppCompactActivity.
Call it from anywhere.

```
((MainActivity) context).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titles.get(position));
```

Answer (score 4):

I made it work by using -

```
toolbar.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
            }
        });
```

Comment: You don't need to use `post` if you're changing title in UI thread, which I think is 90% of cases.

Answer (score 4):

**If you are using `CollapsibleToolbarLayout` along with `Toolbar` then you will need to set title in both the layouts**

set your Toolbar as action bar in `onCreate` method

```
protected void setUpToolBar() {

    if (mToolbar != null) {
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mToolbar.setTitle("List Detail");
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
                .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Later simply update title of toolbar using `setTitle` method

> ```
>  mToolbar .setTitle(productFromShoppingList.getProductName()); 
>  mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(productFromShoppingList.getProductName());
> ```

Comment: This solution works if you're finding that you can set the title once, but can't change it after that.  Make sure you're setting the title of the Collapsing Toolbar.

Comment: if you want to change the title after some time with collapsing toolbar, you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown/57635712#57635712

Answer (score 3):

I have a strange behaviour that may can help you.
This is working but it has no effect in onCreate only:

```
toolbar.setTitle("title");
```

Try to use this in onCreate:

```
yourActivityName.this.setTitle("title")
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by setting the `android:label` attribute of your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name="my activity"
 android:label="The Title I'd like to display" />
```

And then add this line to the onCreate():

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the title for each different activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizza);
    setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.title));
}
```

Comment: setTitle(R.string.title); Event easier, but doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Xml Code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:background="@color/tablayout"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Java Code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to set a static string in the toolbar, the easiest way to do it is to simply set the activity label in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".xxxxActivity"
          android:label="@string/string_id" />
```

The toolbar will get this string without any code. (works for me with v27 libraries.)

Answer (score 2):

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //custom toolbaar
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Abhijeet");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though not immediately relevant to this particular setup, I found that removing "CollapsingToolbarLayout" from my XML that was wrapping my toolbar inside of an AppBarLayout made everything work.

So, this:

```
      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Instead of this:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll|snap">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then, I set the title in the activity's onCreate, before setSupportActionBar() is called.

Comment: you could do that. if you really need the collapsing toolbar layout, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown/57635712#57635712

Comment: @Chantell Osejo this worked for me too, even I was using the same layout. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this option:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation (which you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up#utility)):

> To use the ActionBar utility methods, call the activity's
>   getSupportActionBar() method. This method returns a reference to an
>   appcompat ActionBar object. Once you have that reference, you can call
>   any of the ActionBar methods to adjust the app bar. For example, to
>   hide the app bar, call ActionBar.hide().

That is the solution you actually found. Just thought of giving a reference to the official documentation (which apparently few tend to read).

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can do this:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setTitle(R.string.title)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = true.also { onBackPressed() }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is happening because you are using Toolbar and ActionBar both. Now as you want to use Toolbar as an action bar, the first thing you need to do is disable the decor provided action bar.

The easiest way is to have your theme extend from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood question.

Comment: @HareshChhelana You posted answer but do you know what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I think which is related action bar set tile issue that y i given such ans and when you realize me this i deleted my ans so now you dont worried about my misunderstood brother.

Comment: @PareshMayani thank you for your answer, but it doesn't resolve my problem. Please, check updated question