# getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle() shows nothing

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to show a subtitle in the toolbar but nothing happens:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setTitle("my title");
getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("my subtitle");
```

Title is shown properly but subtitle doesn't.

**EDIT**

It works in another activities, but I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout in this one, so I think is due to that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/usr_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: Does your user.getNick() has valid value?

Comment: @Smit Sure, actually I'm testing it with a literal string

Comment: @vrundpurohit No, inside an activity

Comment: last line should be `activity.getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("my subtitle");`

Comment: @bigdestroyer where do you have this code and what is activity?

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry, it was an error. I'm doing that in onCreate activity method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Material with Extended Toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517166/android-material-with-extended-toolbar)

Comment: @bigdestroyer please review your code .I think sloppy mistake

Answer (score 0):

Do like this `setSubtitle(CharSequence subtitle)` add add it.

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        // Title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.about_toolbar_title);
        toolbar.setSubtitle("My Subtitle");

        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

[**Android official docs.**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setSubtitle(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setTitle("my title");
toolbar.setSubtitle("my subtitle");
```

You need to setSubtitle to toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

use below code without using `Toolbar`

```
 try{
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Sub Title");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try with this. Make sure you are using an `AppCompatActivity`.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Toolbar example");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("Here you go");

    }
```