# Title, etc. not showing in Android Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I've just added an Android Toolbar to an app I'm working on.  The toolbar placement works correctly with the toolbar layout appearing at the top of the display.  However, the toolbar is showing up as a blank colored bar...the App Title and Overflow Icon do not show up in the Toolbar.  Any ideas on how to fix?

ToolbarActivity.java:

```
public abstract class ToolbarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setTitle("app name");
    }
}
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

menu_main.xml:
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32582780/1318946

Answer (score 28, accepted):

EDIT: Ok so this needs to be set in a completely different way to work. I assumed (because I hadn't worked with the `ToolBar` much yet, that when using `setActionBar(toolbar)` it added the custom `ToolBar` to the content view automatically - but that wasn't the case.

So the big issue is that the `ToolBar` is never added to the current content view and hence will never be visible until you actually add the `ToolBar` to the current content view.

There are different approaches, but I'm only gonna show one of the them.

Instead of having a `toolbar.xml` file, you should add the `ToolBar` directly into the layout file of the `Activity`.

Here's an example of the `Activity` class and the XML to go together with the `Activity`:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if(toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My custom toolbar!");
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:minHeight="100dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your `styles.xml` file is correct as it is.

It's important to note, that after setting your `ActionBar` to the custom `ToolBar`, you use the default methods for changing how the `ActionBar` looks like. For instance setting the title, should be set from `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` and not from `toolbar.setTitle()`.

Comment: Ah, I understand.  I inflated with the code you suggested and the Toolbar shows properly.  But the toolbar it is still blank, just a colored bar.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3796660 I changed my answer completely - I had to dig a little around, but the above should be working correctly now - use with your own code :-) In my opinion it's a bit confusing how the `ToolBar` needs to be implemented to use it as the `ActionBar`...

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. I need to do some formatting on the toolbar but the custom Title you used and the default Up arrow and Overflow symbol displayed correctly.  Thank you for sharing your Android knowledge, cheers.

Comment: Yeah change what you need. This was merely an example on how it can be used :-) Always happy to help ;-)

Comment: I get this error: "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead." What should I do?

Comment: @pilat look in your `style.xml` file. You should have this set: `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` in your current active `Style`.

Comment: Oh my! Thanks a bunch! I was looking forever for a solution to this!

Comment: As of today, using `appcompat-v7:24.2.0`, `Toolbar` can be in its own `xml` file and included in activity's layout. However, `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title")` is still the correct approach to set the title.

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-toolbar-example.html

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
  <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest, add the following...

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity.ToolbarActivity"
            android:label="@string/yourStringTitle"
            />
```

Hope this helps