# Support Toolbar Title

Tags: android, android-toolbar

No matter what I do I can't set the title in a support toolbar.  The only thing on the toolbar is an icon regardless of if I set it.

Followed the guidelines here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

I have tried every combination of getSupportActionBar.set... and none of them alter the toolbar at all.

Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.galleryToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("blah blah");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("blah");
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
    ...
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/galleryLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/galleryToolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
```

Theme:

```
<style name="GalleryTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="showcaseViewStyle">@style/CustomShowcaseTheme</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: well what about `mToolbar.setTitle`

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("blah);` typo in the question, or in your code?

Comment: @tyczj It's not well documented but support toolbar is to be used in this manner.

Comment: @Anthony it is not wrong to do that, either way is correct

Comment: SO and Goog claim differently:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265208/title-etc-not-showing-in-android-toolbar

I think the main issue is to use the action item inflation you must set the toolbar and there are quite a few oddities as to how it behaves at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you donot use `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)` to set the Toolbar as the actionbar, the below code snippet will let you change the Title on the Support Toolbar.

Use the **mToolbar** instance to call the **setTitle()** method.

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.galleryToolbar);

    if (mToolbar != null) {
        mToolbar.setTitle("My Title");
    }
```

Moreover , call other methods on the **mToolbar** instance to customise further.

For more info check the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: That will not work for support toolbar, I'm calling it in the manner described by the documentation.

Comment: Updated my answer with the developer docs link. I am using the Support Toolbar myself and this is the way it works. Checkout the setTitle() method in the developer docs.

Comment: That's odd, because these posts claim differently:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265208/title-etc-not-showing-in-android-toolbar
How are you styling the toolbar?

Comment: Found the difference.Updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74759/discussion-between-radix-and-anthony).