# how to pin title in Toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        ...

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I want title stays in Toolbar, not in CollapsingToolbarLayout. So I changed my code from:

```
mCollapsingToolbar = ...
mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(title);
```

to:

```
mTitleBar = ...
setSupportActionBar(mTitleBar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

But the title is not visible. My device is Nexus 6 5.1.0

Thanks in advance.

---

Update 1: I have changed code to this, still not work :(

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

---

Update 2: Here is code snippet for those three views:

```
private void setUpAppBarLayout() {
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar_layout);
    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(extractBackgroundColor());
}

private void setUpCollapsingToolbarLayout() {
    if (null == mCollapsingToolbar) {
        mCollapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    }
}

private void setUpToolbar(String title) {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_main);
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            supportFinishAfterTransition();
        }
    });
    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_group_activity);
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (R.id.action_settings == item.getItemId()) {
                ...
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    mToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    });

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

After called setSupportActionBar(mToolbar), both title and menu are invisible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682548/collapsingtoolbarlayout-settitle-does-not-update-unless-collapsed

Comment: Hi, @ask4solutions What I need is show and keep title in Toolbar. Not update it.

Comment: Check this link it may help you...


[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28265266/2169192

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In order for the Toolbar title to work with the CollapsingToolbarLayout you need to set the ctl's title enabled to false

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 16):

The solution is easy. As Daniel Persson said, you just set `collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);`
or use the XML attribute `app:titleEnabled="false"`
and set the title with the inner Toolbar instead of the CollapsingToolbarLayout, i.e.: `toolbar.setTitle(title);`

It is very simple and it not required workarounds.

Answer (score 10):

It actually looks like the title from the Toolbar is gone when you wrap it inside a CollapsingToolBarLayout, so the only solution I got for this issue is to create a new TextView and add it to the ToolBar, remember that Toolbar is a ViewGroup, so you can add widgets to it. It's not as clean as I would like, but it works for now.

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText(title);
text.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Widget_ActionBar_Title_Inverse);
toolbar.addView(text);
```

Hope I can find an xml-friendly solution for this soon, too.

Comment: for making text appear in the normal place add        text.setPadding(16,0,0,0);

Comment: This solution is not the best. You can read my solution in the post below

Answer (score 7):

The trick here is to set the titleEnabled = false of CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:title="Message"
            app:titleMarginTop="13dp"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Or through code:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: cont use the setTitleEnabled

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in your code

Comment: Can you post your code here. So that we can check where is the problem exist

Comment: Thanks saikrupa. How to pin title?

Comment: I dont want CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsing title, I want the title text stays in Toolbar like title in Actionbar;

Comment: He wants to have the title stay in the toolbar when the collapsible toolbar expands. Instead of move with the collapsing toolbar. If I understand correctly...I'm also trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? Just add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `AppBarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        ...
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:title="My Title"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    ...

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[This is what you get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUQfr.png)