# Hide AppBar when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have an `AppBar` and a horizontal linearlayout (which includes an edit text and two imagebuttons) and other things in my layout. When user scrolls down, **I want `AppBar`(actually, the `Toolbar` to hide**. This is what I have tried, the appbar isn't hiding it just stays there. I followed the [Chris Banes Cheesesquare Sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare).

**Here is the screenshot of my app:**

[image]

When user scrolls, I want that `AppBar/Toolbar` to disappear, and that horizontal layout, which includes the edittext, replace the appbar and stayed there.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> 

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_show" tools:context="com.example.bimpc1.sozluk.GosterActivity"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/mylin">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">
        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/topLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_sil"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/delete"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/et_word"
                android:ems="12"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_getir"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/search"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <!--many views inside scrollview..... -->

        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: at first check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791100/detect-scroll-up-scroll-down-in-listview

Comment: check this out : https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part2)/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Actually, that design seems to be wrong.Why? let me explain that to you.

Except those `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` which it wasn't necessary or using: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in the `LinearLayout` or using that `ScrollView` under the contents or etc, seems like you don't have any idea what's going on.(no problem).

**Note:** the most important thing was, adding:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` which also mentioned here:

http://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

And this flag should hide that section:(`exitUntilCollapsed`)

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

> `exitUntilCollapsed:` When the scroll flag is set, scrolling down will
>   normally cause the entire content to move.

So finally: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf1So.gif

Hope this is what you were looking for, if it wasn't please edit your question and add some screenshots.

Feel free to change the flags or add a new to achieve what you exactly need.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to hide that `Toolbar`(red section) after collapsing, just use this in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
```

Finally, you will get the same result(something like googleplay design).

**Codes:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <!-- Your Scrollable contents should be here - such as,
            ViewPager or etc -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scrollbarSize="15sp"
                android:text="You Contents" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbarly"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:minHeight="190dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/header"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mylin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_sil"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_word"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="12"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_getir"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- And finally, NavigationView -->

    <!-- <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
          android:id="@+id/nav_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          app:headerLayout="@layout/app_header"
          app:insetForeground="@color/app_color_primary_dark"
          app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" /> -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Results:** after collapsing, the searchedittext won't hide:

[image]

**UPDATE:** New way :)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mylin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/topLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sil"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_word"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ems="12"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_getir"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <!-- Your Scrollable contents should be here - such as,
            ViewPager or etc -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scrollbarSize="15sp"
                android:text="You Contents" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- And finally, NavigationView -->

    <!-- <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
          android:id="@+id/nav_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          app:headerLayout="@layout/app_header"
          app:insetForeground="@color/app_color_primary_dark"
          app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" /> -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I added the screenshot of my app, I think what I want is something simpler.

Comment: @jason - Please check my updated answer, i think i found what exactly you were trying.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked! Except the appbar title is gone. Thanks.

Comment: That's the another problem, you can search about it in this site.you're welcome, also looking forward to your bounty :) goodluck

Comment: Also, that section is `Toolbar` and check the following link about that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28265266/4409113

Comment: Is collapsingtoolbarlayout a must? I think it is the place that hides title

Comment: Yeah that's the reason why that `Toolbar` has gone i guess.

Comment: Why is text showing in your example gif? How did you manage that? Thanks.

Comment: Which one? That text `your content`? For that toolbar title you need to check your styles and implement the toolbar, just check the above link.if this answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: @jason - One more thing , i think you can use that without `CollapsingToolbarLayout` too, take a look at this design, i just implemented it by now: paste.ofcode.org/RxSCyXvSw7aen7R4DrLsBP just put the contents in the `AppBarLayout` and see what happens.

Comment: @LinX64 Could you edit your code in the answer for that? I checked that link but it didn't help

Comment: Jason I believe you need to accept @Linx ans since he explained it well, Otherwise post another question.

Comment: The UPDATE answer worked for me. I was using scrollView and BottomAppBar but this solution still worked. I replaced ScrollView with NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 4):

check this out you need to set flag for it in CoordinatorLayout and CollapsingToolbar,

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <!-- Your scrolling content -->

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Answer (score 4):

I hope that this article will help you: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Try using CoordinatorLayout and CollapsingToolbar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">    
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to structure your layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout >
            <ImageView />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <!-- Your scrollable content here -->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Complete tutorial at: http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/

Answer (score 2):

In the `Drawer.Layout` add in `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    .../...
    // add in
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

It's better to separate out your concerns. Using the sample provided by [chrisbanes/cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare), your layout would be better looking like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    .../...
    // add in
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout .../...>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout .../...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        // Why are you using two themes?
        // android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Replace this:

```
    <LinearLayout .../...>
    <View .../...>
    </View>
    <LinearLayout .../...>
        <ImageButton
            .../...
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView .../...>
    <!--many views inside scrollview..... -->
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

With

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

And then use the ViewPager to populate your list.

```
 ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Then you can format this CheeseListFragment to add your image views individually.

It's also unnecessary to keep declaring your schema:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This is an indicator that you are copying and pasting code and not understanding it.

You should also be using a  nestedScrollView without the view, and linear layout above it. Mind you, it's not clear what you are trying to acheive with that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I'm trying to achieve is that when you scroll down, the appbar should hide, but that horizontaly linear layout shouldn't hide. That 's all. I don't think I need a viewpager, I just have scroll view.

Comment: @jason - Can you take a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve? it is unclear and seems like out of the rules of Material Design though.And your codes has a lot of problem.That `ScrollView`, that `LinearLayout` everything seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @MsYvette - Yeah, i saw the answers and most of them were correct since the OP said: `When user scrolls down, I want appbar to hide` i thought he/she wants to achieve something like this flag: `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed`.I'm agree tot, But, needs to edit the question because the OP gave it the question a bounty.

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot of my app.

Comment: @MsYvette - `I think the OP needs to wear the bounty. Maybe learn a lesson from it.` Yeah, it's not clear, it's okay, but let's help him/her somehow :)

Comment: @MsYvette - Right, i agree too, but the question wasn't so clear The OP was trying to do that, All i want to say is, let's help him/her with anyways or something like my answer with clarifying the codes and fixing them :) that's all, Yeah thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide toolbar use the code below.

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: Use layout_scrollFlags like below:

> app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

and your XML file change like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is content_main XML file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```