# Toolbar hides PagerTitleStrip and part of RecyclerView

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, drawerlayout, pagertitlestrip

*[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apHUT.png) and
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpIiY.png) of my app*

The problem is basically this: The PagerTitleStrip and the RecyclerView go below my Toolbar even though I have set layout_behaviour to my ViewPager.

**More detail:**

I have a main activity that uses the layout below and then from it I launch fragments. Before trying the CoordinatorLayout + ViewPager and all of the other fancy stuff I just had a FrameLayout in which I displayed my fragments. However, I decided that I want to use

> ```
> app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
> ```
>
> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

so that my Toolbar disappears when I scroll the recyclerview. I found online that FrameLayout had no behaviour in it to allow me to fix the position of the recyclerView going under the Toolbar and that's why I changed to ViewPager + CoordinatorLayout to manage my fragments.

However, that introduced a few problems. What I want to achieve is - A toolbar with a PagerTitleStrip attached to it, when I scroll the toolbar disappears leaving the PagerTitleStrip visible ideally, maybe it hides as well I don't care that much about that. But I want my Navigation Drawer to keep working and it doesn't. It's like it doesn't exist.

Now, this first layout actually has all of the above features working, but the problem is the strip is below the toolbar and it's not visible unless the Toolbar hides when I scroll. Drawer works. Recycler view items are partially hidden below the Toolbar unfortunately - they don't start scrolling from the right point of the screen even though I have that set -  appbar_scrolling_view_behavior

Layout m_drawerlayout.xml for my main activity to inflate:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/tealfifty"
            android:background="@color/teal">

        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:background="@color/tealDark"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is the code for my app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/teal"
app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/Green.Overlay.LightPopup"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I tried moving elements around, in and out of other components but no success. For example, it seems logical that to make the PagerTitleStrip attached to the Toolbar and share one behaviour I'd have to nest the PagerTitleStrip inside the AppBar layout but PagerTitleStrip has to be a direct child of ViewPager to work...Any suggestions guys about all this? I'm new to all these design functionalities and I researched a lot without success, there are similar topics here but not at all what I need. Seems there's almost nothing on the internet about things I'm trying to do above (there are a few) compared to other basic topics.

If anyone is wondering why I'm using ViewPager when I have no tabs, it's because as I said, FrameLayout has no behaviour allowing me to use a disappearing Toolbar correctly and that's what I found is good to use. I also saw NestedScrollView could be used but I haven't used it ever so... I now want to possibly use the ViewPagerTitle which I guess limits me to ViewPager for the Fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Which the `DrawerLayout` should be the root layout.

**Please see: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout**

> To add a `navigation drawer`, declare your user `interface` with a
>   `DrawerLayout` object **as the root view of your layout**. Inside the
>   `DrawerLayout`, add one view that contains the main content for the
>   screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another
>   view that contains the contents of the `navigation drawer`.

Also, it is not recommended to use `ListView` instead of `NavigationView`.

And here is the doc suggested way to do(except that `ListView`:) ):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**And also:**

> However, that introduced a few problems. What I want to achieve is - A
>   `Toolbar` with a `PagerTitleStrip` attached to it, when I scroll the
>   toolbar disappears leaving the `PagerTitleStrip` visible ideally, maybe
>   it hides as well I don't care that much about that. But I want my
>   `Navigation Drawer` to keep working and it doesn't.

Check my answer about this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241363/4409113

You just put your Toolbar inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbarly"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:minHeight="190dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

It should collapsed and the Toolbar will be hided after that.And if you want to keep that `PagerTitleStrip`(Recommended to use `TabLayout` Nowadays), just put it below the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and above the `</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>` like this:

```
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

That's pretty much it, Goodluck then.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the clarification. I read some more and re-arranged my XML Layout and everything works fine now except for one thing. My NavigationDrawer now goes on top of the Toolbar instead of starting right after the Toolbar like before. Any idea how to fix that? That's how I nested things now: DrawerLayout>CoordinatorLayout>AppBar>ViewPager>PagerTitleStrip<PagerTitleStrip<VIewPager<CoordinatorLayout<Listview<DrawerLayout

Comment: Can i see your current code? please paste it somewhere, i need to see it btw, you're welcome ;)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hs7Q2Ap0 Is there any reason why you suggest that I use CollapsingToolbarLayout when with a regular Toolbar all I need to do is add this to the Toolbar xml: app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" Also, from what I read PagerTitleStrip is not worse than a TabLayout, it's just different, a Tab Layout is recommended for only a few tabs like 3 whereas PagerTitleStrip could have many, like in Google Play store...?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't work with `PagerTitleStrip` so, (a guess) try to use that `ViewPager` Above the `AppBarLayout`.`CollapsingToolbarLayout` just was a test, for see how it should be.Because `TabLayout` is coming with `Support Library`