# Toolbar going on top of Appbar - CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I've been struggling with the `AppBarLayout`/`Toolbar`/`CoordinatorView`. Want the `Toolbar` ***to slide up on scroll,*** and return immediately on scroll down (like most reading apps, g+ is an example also). However, this is what I'm getting:

**Normal:**

[image: Normal]

**A little scroll:**

[image: A little scroll]

**Full scroll:**

[image: Everything scrolled]

**This is my code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="main.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        android:title="Hello World"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/main__activitycontent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**`main__activitycontent`:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="main.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/main__activity">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:text="@string/large_text"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I've been reading a lot of blog posts, but none of their configs seems to work for me. The hide on scroll up/show on scroll down works fine, only the `Toolbar` is moving over the appbar. Checking the Android View Hierarchy I see that they the `Toolbar` is above the dark blue appbar, and they move up together.

**EDIT 1**

Removing the `fitsSytemWindows=true` from the `CoordinatorLayout` leads to the expected behavior, but the appbar becomes white, no matter the bg color for the `CoordinatorLayout`:

[image]

My guess is that the behavior actually didn't change, what happend is that it doesn't cover the appbar anymore, so the toolbar doesn't go over it.

**EDIT 2**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

**EDIT 3**

```
package main;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.ee.oef.refactor.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main__activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main__toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main__menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` it appears your toolbar is going under the system app bar because you set this

Comment: If I remove the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" the behavior works as expected, but the appbar becomes white instead of colorPrimaryDark. I've tried changing the bg color of the CoordinatorLayout, but it remains white.

Comment: have you defined `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>` in your styles.xml under AppTheme ?

Comment: Even changing to #0000FF on the layout does nothing, so it's not a declaration problem. Removing the fitsSystemWindow made the Coordinator Layout start right below the AppBar

Comment: and last thing share the Activity code where your using this layout

Comment: Added the activity. There's nothing much over there.

Comment: Is the activity theme set to AppTheme.NoActionBar in the manifest?

Comment: what is your colorPrimary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

Which you could add this to your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.`enterAlwaysCollapsed` ***is a good practice for `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and not the `Toolbar`.***

**UPDATE:** And i've seen few problems in the layouts and the ids.

For example, not sure you saw that or not but i'll explain that.The first thing is, `Toolbar`'s id: `id_toolbar` which in the `onCreate` is:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main__toolbar);
```

So, just change it to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main__toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

P.s: i just deleted the title and `Scrollflag` which the title is coming from **`Manifest` -> `android:label`** and you need to change it.(if you want to change it, do it programmatically.)

> and return immediately on scroll down (like most reading apps, g+ is
>   an example also).

Just add this to your `Toolbar`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

And finally, here you can see my answer about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241363/4409113

Which we have:

[image]

**Update:** I didn't use:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

In the `CoordinatorLayout` too. as you can see the example here:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml

**Update:** 
To solve the white toolbar problem, set on values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

This gives the appropriate behavior AND appearance.

Comment: I managed to get this state by removing fitsSystemWindow=false on CoordinatorLayout. However, the status bar was not being colored, because the CoordinadorLayout started below the StatusBar. I found a workaround by setting android:windowBackground to primaryDarkColor.

Comment: Update, i saw the `cheesesquare` again, seems like he didn't add that in the `CoordinatorLayout`, but he added it in the `Drawer`, anyways, my answer is the correct answer about that flags i guess.

Comment: I will accept your answer, just add something to it to be complete: set 
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

Comment: Good, but one thing, check this link: http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html Says: **By default**, **`android:statusBarColor` inherits the value of `android:colorPrimaryDark`**, so you don't need that actually, if you saw any weird things, it should be fixed with a real device, i said that because i thought you are using an emulator.

Comment: I added the edit to your answer. should be good. Thank you for the help

Comment: You're welcome, btw you don't need that `statusBarColor` since you have `colorPrimaryDark` ;), happy programming.

Comment: this is the thing I found most strange: it should, but it wasn't. I later checked v21/styles.xml and found that statusBarColor was being overwritten and  being set to transparent (this was the code Studio autogenerates)

Comment: Hmm, strange, thank you for pointing out that v21 too, it should be interesting i will check it out too.goodluck