# Hide ToolBar on View scroll

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using `Fragment` and `RecyclerView` inside.
I would like to hide Fragment's toolBar while I'm scrolling `RecyclerView`. It's work by design, but `Toolbar` hiding not completely.
How to solve this problem?

**Start scroll point:**

[image]

**Final scroll point:**

[image]

Here is `MainActivity.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.avalank.financy.Main2ActivityTest">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **CollapsingToolbar** for achieveing such functionality. You can find a [good tutorial here.](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, i've tried that and that worked without below code in the `Styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Finally, check this answer with two methods/tricks to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241363/4409113

Also, you can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with some flags like:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
```

Also, let's mention that i've deleted this line:

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
```