# How to collapse the toolbar while I'm scrolling through a RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout, android-scroll

I have an activity where I have set NavigationDrawer and works fine. This activity hosts a fragment where I have used:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

To enable the menu. I have added a SearchView and override `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    //Do some search stuff
}
```

And everything works fine. This the layout file of my fragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now I want to collapse the toolbar while I'm scrolling through the `RecyclerView`. I know I can add an `AppBarLayout` and inside it a `Toolbar` in my layout file, but is the any possibility to achieve the same behaviour with the existing one in a ConstraintLayout?

Comment: The animations won't be as smooth and you'll be reinventing the wheel. Better to just add an AppBarLayout and a Toolbar. Also, consider CoordinatorLayout if you'll be adding the appbarlayout

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example

Comment: @sonnet Thank you for that. All examples I've found are using a `CoordinatorLayout`. Is this the best way? If I would still want to achieve this with a `ConstraintLayout`, how should I do?

Comment: @Jorn AFAIK, `CoordinatorLayout` is the only native view that got the functionality that you are looking for. If you want to fully hide the `toolbar`, you'll need an in-depth knowledge about android development to make one.

Answer (score 1):

With `CoordinatorLayout`:

The best thing would have been to use a `CoordinatorLayout`.  A similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475884/how-to-hide-toolbar-when-i-scrolling-content-up-in-android) should be able to help you out.

Since you want to achieve that with `ConstraintLayout`:

You would have to create an `OnScrollListener` class for your `RecyclerView`. The class would have an `onScrolled()` method which would have parameters - dx, dy, the amounts of horizontal and vertical scrolls. [Here](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/#showinghiding-views-when-list-is-scrolling) is a link on how you can follow through with.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of CordinaterLayout.Kindly Check out this answer.

[Hide AppBar when scrolling down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173853/hide-appbar-when-scrolling-down/35241363)

Comment: Thank you but my question is related to a `ConstraintLayout`. Can I achieve the same thing with it? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes ,you can achieve the same the with the ConstraintLayout.
1: Add ParentLayout of CordinateLayout of your ConstraintLayout
2: Use can also use android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
3: Enable nestedscroll view of your rescyclerView.

Comment: This could be a comment. Please don't just answer just to post a link to another existing solution

Comment: @umerfarooq I don't want to use an `AppBarLayout` with a ` Toolbar` in .XML file, I just want to use the existing one. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Use this layout in fragment (Wrap Recyclerview in Nestedscrollview).

In main layout use AppbarLyaout inside Coordinator layout Like this

```
  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/DashCoor"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".Activities.DashboardActivity">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                >
                ​


               //Layout to be collpased

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                />

         </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

         </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope you solve it :)