# Toolbar title not showing in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have this toolbar :

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbarly"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I have this in Java :

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xffffffff);
        myToolbar.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My app");
```

When I run the app, toolbar is showing but not the Title. How can I show title? Thanks.

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); try this and also in which format you are giving color values?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. My color formats are like this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#MAGENTA

Comment: did you try setting title directly to myToolbar?

Comment: @VivekMishra do you mean in the layout? I tried `app:title="My app" `, it didn't work. Also, tried `android:title` but didn't work either.

Comment: no like this myToolbar.setTitle();

Comment: @VivekMishra it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the title from app manifest file. Try

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity"/>
```

Then set the String value property inside your String value resource.

Answer (score 3):

You could include this line in CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

Comment: Why setting titleEnabled to false works ?

Answer (score 0):

Check with below link and it's relative answers.

[Title, etc. not showing in Android Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265208/title-etc-not-showing-in-android-toolbar)

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: I checked that link but it didn't help.

Comment: Try to add this.            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);