# Can getSupportActionBar be null right after setSupportActionBar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Should I null check the `getSupportActionBar()` method even if earlier in that method I have set the support action bar using `getSupportActionBar()`?

In `onCreate()` I have the three lines

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(TITLE_KEY));
```

Android Studio then gives me the **warning**

```
"Method invocation may produce java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

Assuming that the **findViewById** method does return a valid `ToolBar` object, do I still need to null check the `getSupportActionBar()` method or is it safe to just ignore the warning?

Comment: Warning is not an Error. And the warning which you are talking about says "it may produce", don't say 'it must produce'.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar if it was "it must produce" what  would it be for then??? the getter method that always return null is **useless**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### My suggestion is :- Not to check for null because Warnings are not Errors

warning which you are talking about says "it may produce".It don't say 'will must produce'.

But if you want to double sure you can check for null

Answer (score 3):

That may produce a NullPointer exception.

You have created a new Toolbar object, you can use `toolbar.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(TITLE_KEY));` to set the title. You'll need to do this before you call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

There is no need to call `getSupportActionBar()`, since the actionbar that has been set is the toolbar. So you can directly use that object to edit your toolbar. That is faster than getSupportActionBar();

Comment: The question is pertinent some stuff can't be done through `ToolBar`, for example `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`

Comment: @Mood That's true, but for the things that the questioner wants to do Toolbar is fine

Comment: Sorry @tim687 I went over the question quickly.

Comment: I looked at this. It turns out that doing toolbar.setTitle() after setSupportActionBar() does not work. I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown which talks about that as well. Unlike his example however I did work for me if I did toolbar.setTitle() before calling setSupportActionBar()

Comment: @MungoRae Thanks! I've updated the answer. Please accept it if this solved your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did help this specific case using setTitle() but as Mood pointed out, I was more asking about dealing with the getSupportActioBar method in general and I feel that NileshJarad's answer was more what I was looking for. Your answer was very useful however.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having this warning you can always check if the `ActionBar` object is null.

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (mActionBar != null) {
        mActionBar.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(TITLE_KEY));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not null check this. Because if the assumption fails (for example if `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` starts returning `null` because you introduce a bug in another file in your project), you **do** want a NullPointerException to be thrown, so you easily find the error when you test.

In other words: In my opinion, the best approach is to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).

My code looks like this, with a comment that silence the warning:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions: Action bar should always be present. If not, we prefer a NullPointerException here.
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```