# Method invocation 'setTitle' may produce 'java.lang.NullpointerException'

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I tried to set a title for an `ActionBar` with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.artist));
    super.onResume();
}
```

but Android Studio shows me this warning:

[image: Error warning]

I searched on StackOverflow that it will be fixed by adding this code `if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)` in front of my code. But it causes an error in my script. 
I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: you mean `if(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()!=null)` though you should use a callback mechanism

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can getSupportActionBar be null right after setSupportActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805899/can-getsupportactionbar-be-null-right-after-setsupportactionbar)

Comment: after i add 'if(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()!=null' inf front of my code the warn keep showing.

Comment: setSupportActionBar(toolbar); write onCreate() in Main activity than you will right in your fragment ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.artist));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options to do what you asked for:

### 1 - Ignore the warning

No need to explain further, this is not an error

### 2 - The elegant solution

Wrap your line with 'if' statement to make sure it's not null

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.artist));
}
```

### 3 - Use assert

```
assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.artist));
```

### 4 - Move the warning

If you use 'getSupportActionBar' in multiple locations, you can remove all of those warnings and in return you will only receive a warning on the @NonNull usage.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return super.getSupportActionBar();
}
```