# Android Toolbar set title explanation

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have my app Toolbar here:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

When i want to set the screen title, i have to do the following:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
if (bar != null) {
    bar.setTitle(SCREEN_TITLE);
}
```

My questions is, why when calling the toolbar.setTitle() is not working. But instead i need to get the action bar first and then i can set the title?

P.S. In the other hand, I can set the Toolbar icon normally without getting the action bar as so:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In android app Toolbar.setTitle method has no effect – application name is shown as title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown)

Comment: not a duplicated. I am not asking how to set the title. Code is working fine for setting the title. I need an explanation about how and why this code logic is needed.

Comment: look through the answer for that question and you will find the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Toolbar` is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts.

Unlike Action bar , toolbar is not part of window decor.You defines it and place it just like any other widget...therefor you have freedom to place it anywhere in the parent layout.

You have freedom to put any widget inside toolbar.

You can define multiple toolbars.

`Toolbar` may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy. An application may choose to designate a `Toolbar` as the action bar for an Activity using the `setActionBar()` method.

As `Toolbar` is generalization of `ActionBar`. you have to first set `Toolbar` as `ActionBar` then you can use all method of `ActionBar`.

**EDIT:**

Here is [Link](http://mrengineer13.com/how-to-use-toolbar-to-replace-your-actionbar/) that explains Toolbar concept.

Here is [bug link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763) reported in android issues: In issue they suggest that Once you call `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`, the Action Bar is then responsible for handling the title, meaning that you need to call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...)` to set a custom title. It also gives explanation about why `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white);` works.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer kinda helps me understand better. But the question is, why i can use toolbar.setNavigationIcon() to change the back icon but cannot use toolbar.setTitle().

Comment: Here is bug link reported in android issues: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763.   In issue they suggest that Once you call setSupportActionBar(Toolbar), the Action Bar is then responsible for handling the title, meaning that you need to call getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...) to set a custom title.

Comment: I guess it's a design pattern issue from Google, but i got the idea! thanks