# Toolbar (SupportActionBar) title changes to app name on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I have this code in my Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm updating the ActionBar title from various fragments like this in `onResume()`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setTitle(title);
}
```

This is working fine, but after orientation change, the title changes to the app name again. How I can overcome this?

EDIT:
After investigating more, I tried this and found this weird behaviour:
Added this code where I was setting title in Fragments:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("SWAPNIL", "IN RUN BEFORE: " + actionBar.getTitle());
            actionBar.setTitle(title);
            Log.d("SWAPNIL", "IN RUN AFTER : " + actionBar.getTitle());
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

And here's the log:

```
10-13 10:27:04.526 3719-3719/com.example.xxxx D/SWAPNIL: onResumeHelp
10-13 10:27:07.528 3719-3719/com.example.xxxx D/SWAPNIL: IN RUN BEFORE: MY APP NAME
10-13 10:27:07.528 3719-3719/com.example.xxxx D/SWAPNIL: IN RUN AFTER : title
10-13 10:27:21.012 3719-3719/com.example.xxxx D/SWAPNIL: onResumeHelp
10-13 10:27:24.013 3719-3719/com.example.xxxx D/SWAPNIL: IN RUN BEFORE: title
10-13 10:27:24.013 3719-3719/com.example.xxxx D/SWAPNIL: IN RUN AFTER : title
```

It was getting changed as per logs but wasn't reflected in UI.
Please help me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, finally, after spending 2 days on this silly thing, I got the solution (I would say workaround).

This is probably a nested `Fragment` bug.

I have nested Fragment structure. As we know `Fragment.getActivity()` returns parent `Activity`. After lot of debugging I observed that if you call `getActivity()` after orientation change (even inside `Fragment.onActivityCreated()`) it returns reference of the old `Activity` except in top most parent fragment where it correctly returns the newly created `Activity`.

So I've written this method to get current `Activity` from any `Fragment`:

```
/**
 * When inside a nested fragment and Activity gets recreated due to reasons like orientation
 * change, {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment#getActivity()} returns old Activity but the top
 * level parent fragment's {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment#getActivity()} returns current,
 * recreated Activity. Hence use this method in nested fragments instead of
 * android.support.v4.app.Fragment#getActivity()
 *
 * @param fragment
 *  The current nested Fragment
 *
 * @return current Activity that fragment is hosted in
 */
public Activity getActivity(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment == null) {
        return null;
    }
    while (fragment.getParentFragment() != null) {
        fragment = fragment.getParentFragment();
    }
    return fragment.getActivity();
}
```

Comment: Unsure if I should say well done or thanks. This is a good lesson for every Android developer. Google should take these bugs seriously than just release more unfinished Android versions.

Comment: Mark this as answer since it actually solves the problem.

Comment: @Sufian thanks :) I'm surely gonna file this on Android bug reporting when I get some time to properly document the issue.

Comment: where do you call this method?

Comment: @LukeAllison
I've a base Fragment from which all of my Fragments extend. I wrote above method in that base Fragment and call it inside other Fragments. So instead of calling  
`ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`
I'm calling  
`ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(this)).getSupportActionBar();`  
from all the Fragments.

Comment: the solution is more much simple: just use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()`, on Kotlin it's `supportActionBar?.title = "NAME"`

Answer (score 6):

You need to see the answer written by sorianiv here:
[In android app Toolbar.setTitle method has no effect – application name is shown as title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown)

Adding the additional `toolbar.setTitle("")` resolved this issue for me.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Profiles");
```

Comment: the question you mentioned is bit different. I face the problem I posted because Android is returning me old `Activity` when I call `getActivity()` inside a `Fragment` (old Activity in the sense Activity gets recreated due to orientation change etc.). And hence my solution.

Comment: Your solution is definitely more complete but I passed you this link as it solves the exact symptom you were having, that your toolbar was reverting to the app name after rotating. This solved the issue for me. If any more issues pop up due to the wrong activity being returned then I'll implement your solution.

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me. I was calling `setTitle()` inside of the `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask`. It seems like you only need to call `setTitle("")` in `onCreate()` to make it possible to change the title further on with `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("...");`

Comment: no need to call this method twice, just use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` once instead of referencing to toolbar view, p.s. on Kotlin it's `supportActionBar?.title = "NAME"`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue, and I solved it by using `getSupportActionBar` instead of `toolbar`.

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're activity is getting recreated when you rotate the screen. So onCreate is getting called again, and you have not set a title there.

Add the following to your onCreate:

```
actionBar.setTile("Enter title here")
```

Comment: He is setting the title in `onResume()` of fragments. This will most likely not work.

Comment: Yeah, Fragment's `onResume()` will get called after Activity's `onCreate()`

Comment: Add some breakpoints and debug through and see what steps your app goes through after the rotation. Then you will know if your onResume() is being called and what is being called to change your actionbar title

Comment: @RED_ from where I can debug, since it is the system who is changing title to app name. All I could do was to check if `onResume()` is called after Activity's `onCreate()` which is happening.

Comment: @SwapnilBhoite add breakpoints in different methods of your fragment and activity and goto **Run -> Debug 'myApp'** (considering you are using Android Studio). If you find a solution, post it as answer so it helps someone in future. :)

Comment: @Sufian I found the problem but no solution yet, I added logs in on`Create` of `Activity` and `onResume` of `Fragment`, turns out after rotation, when Activity gets recreated, `getActivity` from Fragment is returning old Activity (and so does old ActionBar)!
Here's log:(I'm logging `Activity#toString`)

Comment: `10-14 21:55:24.968 29718-29718/com.example.xxxxxxx D/SWAPNIL: onCreate: com.xxxxxxxxx.activities.ParentActivity@2b29230d
10-14 21:55:25.006 29718-29718/com.example.xxxxxxx D/SWAPNIL: onResume: com.xxxxxxxxx.activities.ParentActivity@2b29230d
10-14 21:55:32.400 29718-29718/com.example.xxxxxxx D/SWAPNIL: onCreate: com.xxxxxxxxx.activities.ParentActivity@2269072a
10-14 21:55:32.472 29718-29718/com.example.xxxxxxx D/SWAPNIL: onResume: com.xxxxxxxxx.activities.ParentActivity@2b29230d`

Comment: I really don't know what to do now!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change your Action Bar / ToolBar, in onPostCreate() method in your Activity..
The code is just simple. I try to change my emulator / device orientation for many times and it works like charm..

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met the problem as the title of the toolbar is set as empty ("") at the onCreateView, but after screen is rotated, then the the title bar shows application name not the empty string.
This I also tried set empty string at the onResume, and finally it works! thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add in Manifest file

```
<activity
     android:name=".Activity"
     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

or
code in onConfigChange()

```
if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    // Set Title for Landscape
 }else{
   // Set Title for Portrait
```

Comment: Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) says, "This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications."
I think this is not a proper solution, rather a hacky way.

Comment: This configuration change is recommended far too often and is never the solution. Unless you want the exact same layout to remain after rotating do not use this.