# Android SupportActionBar does not refresh title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

I have a problem with refreshing ActionBar title. The application is rather simple, currently it only have one activity:
`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_count_scrolling"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabReset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The layout `content_count_scrolling` contains only `NestedScrollView` with `RecyclerView` inside.

My case is, when I enter a digit into the `EditText` in any of RecyclerView's row, it sets a value in the data model as well as recalculate the total value (sum from all rows). This total value should be set as `ActionBar.title`. To do this I am also using RxBus. MainActivity as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_scrolling);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");

        mRxBus = getRxBusSingleton();        
        // ....
    }
}

public void refreshActionBarTitle() {
    String total = Data.getTotal();
    Timber.d("Refresh bar title with value="+total);

    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Title "+total);

    // testes also with:
    // getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title "+total);

    Timber.d("Title after refresh: " + getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
}
```

`

Method `refreshActionBarTitle()` is triggered by RxBus. Once when method is triggered, the title of the `ActionBar` also is set (checked with logs and debugger). The issue is, that ActionBar is not invalidated and redrawn. This is done only after rotate the screen, which is obvious.

So, please help me with correct invalidate the toolbar. I have to notice also, that this event will be triggered after avery change in `EditText`, not only after changing the focus, so i cannot invalidate eg. whole screen.

I have checked also advices from [Toolbar (SupportActionBar) title changes to app name on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103079/toolbar-supportactionbar-title-changes-to-app-name-on-orientation-change), but they did not help me.

Comment: Try adding getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

Comment: I think that I also did it. Or rather check it with `false` and then `true` to enforce  invalidate. Didn't work. I tried also `Toolbar` invalidate, and set drawer. And also nothing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fixed. I should use `CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle()` method. This one works