# How to update toolbar title?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-databinding

I want to update the title of my toolbar programmatically after changes have been made to an entity that is bound to the layout via data binding.

Excerpt from my layout (data binding works fine when bound initially):

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:title="@{entity.title}"/>
```

My activity's `onCreate` method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.my_layout);

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        MyEntity entity = (MyEntity) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(MyEntity.class.getName());
        binding.setEntity(entity);
    }
```

When the entity is edited I want to update the UI which I tried the following way in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   ...
   binding.setEntity(editedEntity); // this seems not to be sufficient and getSupportActionBar().getTitle() still returns the old value
   binding.toolbar.setTitle(editedEntity.getTitle()); // getSupportActionBar().getTitle() returns the updated value but the UI does not show it
   setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar); // does not help either
   ...
}
```

So, the problem is that although I can debug and verify that `getSupportActionBar().getTitle()` returns the new and updated title at some point, this change is not reflected in the UI.

How can I force an update of my toolbar?

Comment: Have you set your activity theme to be of type NoActionBar using 
"android:windowActionBar" and "android:windowNoTitle" attributes ?

Comment: Yes, I indeed use `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` and `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`.

Comment: I should have search for "refresh" rather. Now I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672418/android-supportactionbar-does-not-refresh-title which explains my problem. I needed to bind the title to the CollapsingToolbarLayout. Now it works :) I flagged my question as duplicate now.

Answer (score 4):

you can set title using,

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

Comment: No, that does not work. At least the updated value is  not reflected in the UI like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using

```
getSupportActionBar().getTitle() 
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar); 
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(editedEntity.getTitle());
```

Just changed the sequence of setting title of toolbar and setting toolbar as supportActionBar.

Comment: No, that does not change anything. I'm pretty sure the problem is not related to the data binding, since even `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Updated!");` does not seem to have any result.