# getSupportActionBar().setTitle() vs toolbar.setTitle()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-titlebar

I am aware that **there are two methods to setting a title in an Android `Activity`**.

Assuming I already have the following code...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    ...

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

...I can use either this...

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

...or this...

```
toolbar.setTitle("My title");
```

...to set my title.

My question is, **which is the better practice**?

Comment: Since you have a Toolbar object, why not use its methods?

Comment: If you already have Toolbar, certainly is better practice to use its methods. So use toolbar.setTitle().

Comment: Sometimes I miss method chaining..

`setSupportActionbar(toolbar).setTitle(R.string.title);`  But one can't even `setSupportActionbar(toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title));`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you call `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`,
then the Action Bar is then responsible for handling the title, therefore you need to call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");` to set a custom title.

Also check this link where `toolbar.setTitle("My title");` may cause problem like below:-
[In android app Toolbar.setTitle method has no effect – application name is shown as title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown)

And toolbar is the general form of action bar.

We can have multiple toolbars as layout widget but action is not.

Thus better approach is to use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");`

Comment: Does this also mean that `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)` is better practice than `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(int)`, or are these slightly different?

Answer (score 0):

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The purpose of this line is to set the passed in toolbar as the activities app bar. So in this way either way is perfectly acceptable; personally as you have already created a toolbar, I would set the title of toolbar before passing it using the above method.