# Issue with setting android's appBar/toolbar title multiple times

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I'm developing an android app and I'm stuck in organizing the layout in a input form activity. I would like to organize the layout of my activity like this sample (found in google android's docs): https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3Skg2b19UVS1LSmc/components_textfields_labels2.png . So a big app bar will contain one or two text field, referencing the name and the description of a user's activity, and within the activity layout's content the rest of input controls. 
The behaviour I would reach is:

1. the activity title is initially empty and toolbar collapsed
2. when I get down the toolbar the text input appear and the user insert some text
3. when the user collapse the toolbar, the activity title (that is, the toolbar title) must be set to the input text value

The problem is that only one time this mechanism works: once set value and collapse the toolbar, when I get down again the toolbar, set the text input value and collapse the toolbar, the title is not setted, that is, setTitle has no effect over the first time.

I will now list my code: I tried to use a custom app bar layout, a collapsing tool bar layout, a toolbar and a text input in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.davide.inputformapp.MainActivity">

    <com.example.davide.inputformapp.MyAppBarLayout.MyAppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.example.davide.inputformapp.MyAppBarLayout.MyAppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

where MyAppBarLayout is the class defined in this way(the code is not mine, I found here in a stackoverflow discussion):

```
public class MyAppBarLayout extends AppBarLayout
    implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    private State state;
    private OnStateChangeListener onStateChangeListener;

    public MyAppBarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyAppBarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (!(getLayoutParams() instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
                || !(getParent() instanceof CoordinatorLayout)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "MyAppBarLayout must be a direct child of CoordinatorLayout.");
        }
        addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (verticalOffset == 0) {
            if (onStateChangeListener != null && state != State.EXPANDED) {
                Log.d("MYAPP","---> EXPANDED");
                onStateChangeListener.onStateChange(State.EXPANDED);
            }
            state = State.EXPANDED;
        } else if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            if (onStateChangeListener != null && state != State.COLLAPSED) {
                Log.d("MYAPP","---> COLLAPSED");
                onStateChangeListener.onStateChange(State.COLLAPSED);
            }
            state = State.COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            if (onStateChangeListener != null && state != State.IDLE) {
                Log.d("MYAPP","---> IDLE");
                onStateChangeListener.onStateChange(State.IDLE);
            }
            state = State.IDLE;
        }
    }

    public void setOnStateChangeListener(OnStateChangeListener listener) {
        this.onStateChangeListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnStateChangeListener {
        void onStateChange(State toolbarChange);
    }

    public enum State {
        COLLAPSED,
        EXPANDED,
        IDLE
    }
}
```

The code in the main activity's onCreate() method is:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
textInput = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInput);
final MyAppBarLayout collapsableAppBar = (MyAppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setTitle(null);

collapsableAppBar.setOnStateChangeListener(new MyAppBarLayout.OnStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChange(MyAppBarLayout.State toolbarChange) {
        String value = textInput.getText().toString();
        toolbar.setTitle(value);
    }
});
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
davide

Comment: Maybe your `onStateChange` not called? Did you try to set a breakpoint there?

Comment: Yes it is reached! The setTitle() method however has no effect.

Comment: You have to change title like this `getSupportActionBar.setTitle(value);` on `setOnStateChangeListener`

Answer (score 3):

set "android:id" to CollapsingToolbarLayout. find it in activity and set title to it. 
I have tried many answers but only setting title to  CollapsingToolbarLayout worked.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace

```
toolbar.setTitle(value)
```

with

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(value)
```

as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26506858/1219012)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change title like this :
instead of

`toolbar.setTitle(value);`

do

`getSupportActionBar.setTitle(value);`

on

`setOnStateChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

it may not be a good solution but one way to get every thing working is by creating custom action Bar 
custom_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/yourcolorforactionbar" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimagetoset" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@android:drawable/menubutoon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

}
```