# How to get text from EditText and Show on ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-actionbar, fragment

I have EditText in which user type their Account Number. Now what i want that when user stop typing his Account Number in EditText then i want to show that Account Number in ActionBar. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26506858/5471104

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In android app Toolbar.setTitle method has no effect – application name is shown as title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown)

Comment: how do you know its stop typing?want to do on any click or length of string?

Comment: Title Already showing on action bar I want to show these Right side of title.

Comment: I used "addTextChangedListener" to know user stop typing.

Comment: And still don't know when user stop typing.

Answer (score 0):

This code may work:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(editText.getText().toString());
```

If you want set the title in the right of the action bar, It is recommended to use `Toolbar` for you can custom the layout.

Comment: Thanks L. Swifter. Title Already showing on action bar I want to show these Right side of title.

Comment: @MoinKhan It's better to use `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Something like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWathcer(){
    void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s.getText().toString());
    }
});
```