# How to change the toolbar's title in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

My android app has a toolbar and I wan to change the title of it. I used toolbar.setTitle() but it is not working... Please help. What should I do? I tried getSupportActionBar().setTitle() but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In android app Toolbar.setTitle method has no effect – application name is shown as title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `this.setTitle(title);` in `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to set the title

```
 Toolbar   mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```