# How to change title in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I try to change the title of my MainActivity outside the `onCreate()` method. It seems to work inside `onCreate()`, but if I try to change it programmatically, it doesn't do anything.

My onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedSong);
```

I already tried outside the `onCreate()`:

```
 public void updatetitle(String title) {
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedSong);
        ((MainActivity) this).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedSong);
        setTitle(selectedSong); 
}
```

None of these works. When I debug the code. The code in the toolbar object is updated, but the view isn't refreshed. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: set it on the toolbar instance before you set the actionBar

Comment: you mean like that:  
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(selectedSong);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Yes. Since that sets the properties before its loaded

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Have you tried [set up the title through the Toolbar some time after setting the SupportActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35430590/3792350)

Comment: Yes, I tried ... nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Write `setTitle()` on top in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle(selectedSong); //*
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I like to change the title outside onCreate. I am able to set it in onCreate, but later on, I can't updated.