# Activity.setTitle doesn't work in runOnUiThread block

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

I need to get a `Note()` object from my room database from a background thread and set the title of the note as my activity title, but `title = note.title` doesn't work and I see my application name in the toolbar. I have also tried `supportActionBar?.title` and `toolbar.title` but none of them solved the issue. I'm sure that the database is giving me the right data and I don't know where is the problem. Any help is appreciated.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_note)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    intent.extras?.also {
        val id = it.getInt(ID_EXTRA)
        Thread(Runnable {
            note = db.noteDao().getNote(id)
            runOnUiThread {
                title = note.title
                tvShowNote.text = note.note
                tvShowTime.text = note.time.format()
            }
        }).start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you changing your `toolbar` title?

Comment: @ZUNJAE `Thread(Runnable {
            note = db.noteDao().getNote(id)
            runOnUiThread {
                title = note.title
            }
        }).start()`

Comment: @ZUNJAE in onResume()

Comment: room by default runs query off the main thread, you can safely use live data returned to update ui elements

Comment: @KaranMer `room by default runs query off the main thread` do you have any proof for that? You need to use LiveData and attach a listener yourself. By default the queries are on the main thread.

Comment: @SoroushLotfi I can't see where you change the title. You're only calling `title = note.title`. What is `title`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown

Comment: @ZUNJAE Karan Mer is right. If you put the queries in `init {}` block in `ViewModel` they run off the main thread.

Comment: @ZUNJAE This is Kotlin dude not Java. `title` in kotlin means `setTitle()` in Java

Comment: refer the docs https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data

Comment: @KaranMer You're right I can use livedata. Thanks for reminding. But I still doesn't understand why `title =  ""` doesn't work in my code.

Comment: also setTitle is method of support action bar, calling title will simply understand is activity's param which is not the case.

Comment: You need to `set title` for the toolbar. As such, the code should be `(your_action_bar).title`

Comment: Room only allows query on the main thread if you turn on `allowMainThreadQueries`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set something like this.

```
supportActionBar!!.title = title //your_title_put_here
```

Have you tried the same without runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 0):

setTitle is method of action bar, you need to use actionbar's instance to set its property. try using below code after you have set your toolbar as support actionbar.

```
val actionBar = supportActionBar
actionBar!!.title = "your_title"
```