# How to execute setTitle() for an ActionBar in an activity's observe call for a ViewModel's LiveData object?

Tags: java, android, androidx

In an activity file, when I write `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...)` in an instantiated observer interface for a view model's `LiveData` value, the action bar's title doesn't change on the observable's updates.

Toolbar setup inside the `onCreate` method in my activity file:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

mViewModel.getValue().observe(this, mValue -> getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mValue));
```

The field definition and getter code of `mValue` in my view model:

```
protected MutableLiveData<String> mValue = new MutableLiveData();
```

```
public LiveData<String> getValue() {
    return mValue;
}
```

To clarify, the observable's value (e.g. `mValue`) is being passed to the lambda observer in the activity file, as expected. And `setSupportActionBar().setTitle()` works like expected when called like normal i.e. outside the lambda observer, also as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown/57635712#57635712) (thanks to [user1506104](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506104/user1506104)) to changing the toolbar's title, which did not use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()`.

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

mViewModel.getValue().observe(this, mValue -> {
    toolbarLayout.setTitle(mValue);
});
```

Where `R.id.toolbar_layout` is the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that parents `R.id.toolbar` in the activity's respective layout resource.

I do not know *why* it works unfortunately.