# I'm unable to set title for a custom tool bar in android

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

here's my code

```
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView tootbarTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.customActionBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Log In");

}
}
```

Here's my XML for custom tool bar.
I also tried using view layout inflater to change this textview  dynamically but didnt
workded But I have to create diffn layout multiple times if i dont get solution to this
problem  lol

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_gradient"
    android:id="@+id/customActionBar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

  <!-- 
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to STA!"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="20dp"/> -->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Error

```
09-20 19:31:19.871 13900-13900/com.aditya.projectapp.sta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.aditya.projectapp.sta, PID: 13900
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aditya.projectapp.sta/com.aditya.projectapp.sta.LogInActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.aditya.projectapp.sta.LogInActivity.onCreate(LogInActivity.java:36)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Here's all my imports in-case if i have mistaken in this please let me know

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.Text;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown
You need to write toolbar.setTitle("")

Comment: Nah I already tried it and it still says that im invoking it on a null reference :(

Comment: I always use a custom layout for toolbar with relative layout. but I think you are having a simple issue just focus more. debug your setSupportActionBar()

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think i have tried everything but nothing worked out..Im just gonna create a new layout of toolbar for every new activity and will use default textview..Because I only have like 2 activities in my app I know its not a good practice but what can i do this point

Answer (score 0):

```
Actionbar actionbar = getActionbar();

or

Actionbar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

actionbar.setTitle("your title goes here.");
```

Comment: Yea but how can i set my custom toolbar as action bar?