# Android Fragment Change Title

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with my fragments. Basically, I have an app which has a navigation drawer and 4 buttons on the activity. When each button is pressed, it will display another fragment. The problem I have is that I want to display the correct title on the `ActionBar`. I can display the selected item from the navigation on the `ActionBar`. But when I pressed the button to go to another fragment, I cannot display the title on the `ActionBar`. Any ideas?

Here's my sample code:
**HomeActivity.class**

```
 private void displayView(final int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MyProfileFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        drawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }

}
```

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment() {
}

CardView card_cart, card_scan, card_categories, card_about;
Intent i;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    initControls(rootView);
    return rootView;
}

private void initControls(View rootView) {

    card_cart = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_cart);
    card_scan = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_scan);
    card_categories = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_categories);
    card_about = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_about);

    card_categories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), CategoriesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    card_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyCartFragment nextFrag = new MyCartFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, nextFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });

    card_about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AboutGrabHutFragment aboutFrag = new AboutGrabHutFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setBreadCrumbTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.about))
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, aboutFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();


        }
    });

    card_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), ScanActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

In the `HomeFragment` will those 4 buttons be found. On a button click, will go to another fragment. I can display that using this:

```
card_about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AboutGrabHutFragment aboutFrag = new AboutGrabHutFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setBreadCrumbTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.about))
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, aboutFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            getActivity().setTitle("About");

        }
    });
```

But the problem is when I go back, the title is still `About`.

Comment: Look this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705242/1770868

Comment: for anyone that have stumbled here and using navigation drawer, your answer may be to update the your destination labels see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646720/how-to-change-label-attribute-of-a-destination-in-navigation-controller)

Comment: There is another answer for that in this post. It is newer and takes care of the new ideas implemented lately as MVVM patterns.

Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18011671/9205277

Answer (score 22):

On the required fragment's onCreateView() method, call the setTitle("") method  of your Main Activity. This way you don't event need to check for a back press event.

this worked for me

eg***

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.id.your_fragment_layout, container,
                false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Your actionbar title");

        return rootView;
    }
```

**Update:**

you can change the title by overriding the  `onResume` method. And for the safe side, you can also override `setUserVisibleHint` and change the title when fragment `isVisibleToUser`.

Comment: In case of adding fragment to BackStack this solution not work.

Answer (score 8):

If someone uses Kotlin and *@Sachin Rao* answer doesn't work (like in my case) I made extensions functions to change title:

```
fun Fragment.setActivityTitle(@StringRes id: Int) {
    (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = getString(id)
}

fun Fragment.setActivityTitle(title: String) {
    (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = title
}
```

Usage (at any point in fragment):

```
setActivityTitle(R.string.title)
setActivityTitle("Title")
```

Comment: The code could be improved to:
`(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = title`
so the app wouldn't crash if the activity doesn't implement `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 3):

I used a onBackStackChangedListener in my MainActivity and use it to update al kinds of stuff when you navigate in the app. You're already manually changing the title so try something like this :

```
//manager is my FragmentManager
manager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            //I'm using this check to check if i'm on my MainFragment, you can use this in al kinds of ways. Decide yourself if you use it or not.
            if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
                Class<? extends Fragment> FragClass;
                //mCurrentFragment is my global Fragment variable to do and check stuff with as below.
                FragClass = mCurrentFragment.getClass();
                if ((FragClass == DesiredFragment.class)) {
                    this.setTitle("desired title");
                } else if ((FragClass == OtherDesiredFragment.class)) {
                    //hope this helps.
                } //etc..
            }
        }
    });
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Class<? extends Fragment> FragClass;
        FragClass = mCurrentFragment.getClass();
        if ((FragClass == HomeFragment.class)) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
            popFragment();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void popFragment() {
    try {
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            manager.popBackStack();
            manager.executePendingTransactions();
            ArrayList<Fragment> reversedFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(manager.getFragments());
            Collections.reverse(reversedFragments);
            for (Fragment fragment : reversedFragments) {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    try {
                        mCurrentFragment = (BaseFragment) fragment;
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried doing this but when I went back, it's not changing the title

Comment: Do you have the @Override OnBackPressed function and do you handle the backstack while pressing on back?

Comment: Check at the updated answer, it controls the backstack while pressing the back button. BaseFragment is my custom class for my Fragments, so in your case it would probably be Fragment.

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes did this help you / or have you found another solution?

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me, what worked was setting the label in mobile_navigation.xml (the navigation xml file)

```
    android:label="@string/title_library"
```