# How to change label attribute of a destination in navigation controller?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-components

I am trying to use navigation controller in Android

[image]

as you can see in the image above, I set the `label` attribute of my destination to be 'Home'.

and this label, will show like title in my toolbar.
can I change that label programatically ? because I want to set my toolbar title dynamically.

I have tried to change the toolbar title using `toolbar.title = "some title here"` but it will always be overlapped the title from that label.

so how to solve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it in your activity like below it's worked for me:

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_controller_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)


    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.mainFragment -> toolbar.title = "ok"
            else -> {
                toolbar.title = "General"
            }
        }
    }
```

or if you want to change from your fragment do like below:

```
 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    (activity as MainActivity).toolbar.title = "changed"
}
```

Comment: but the string should come from my destination(fragment). so what should I do ? I want to change it dynamically

Comment: Hi @Alexa289 , any news? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this, all solutions didn't work for me. But after extensive research I came across the solution below;

Create a string

```xml
<string name="my_label">You are on {label}</string>
```

In your `nav-graph.xml` file. Use the above string as a label and create an argument and it should have the same name as the label

```xml
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/your_fragment"
        .....
        android:label="@string/my_label">

        <argument
            android:name="label"
            app:argType="string" />

    </fragment>
```

So, in your fragment you can pass the label name like this;

```
  val direction = YourFragmentDirections
                .action_to_your_fragment(label = "forum")
  findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

Viola, it works like charm

Comment: This worked best for me, thanks so much, much better than overriding onStart() each time as accepted answer

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you @masokaya

Comment: Finally, the best solution for navigation. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the label in your `nav_graph.xml`, for that fragment, then set a title for your toolbar in the fragment/activity.