# Change ActionBar title using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

- I'm using Actionbar.
- I have a Fragment call Favorites where i save some contacts as favorites.
- When you click on one contact it takes me to another fragment an put the contact number on a editText.
- The new fragment is call Transfers.

So my problem is that when the user clicks the contact, that takes me to the other fragment but the title on the action bar still with the favorite title and not the new one, how to change that title?

I have already try to use `setTitle` on the click method but still not working.

Comment: Look this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705242/1770868

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In your activity:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

And in your fragment (You can put it onCreate or onResume):

```
 public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    // Set title bar
    ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity())
            .setActionBarTitle("Your title");

}
```

Comment: Great sample i didn't realize that onResume could override my Tittle

Comment: it changes perfectly but its saving to all fragments after changing

Comment: if I would change fragment it should be changed as I have fragment on BottomNavigationViewEx, its not working for change fragment

Answer (score 25):

In your fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActivity().setTitle("Team B");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_b, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Navigation Components from Android Jetpack. The action bar reads the Label attribute for the fragment name. Not sure if this is a proper fix, but if you change the Label text in the Navigation Editor, it will be read by the supportActionBar that is set up in the Activity hosting the fragments.[image: Navigation Editor Attributes Tab]

Comment: can we change fonts of action bar using jetpack?

Answer (score 4):

Em Kotlin você pode usar o seguinte código nas funções: onCreateView, onStart e onResume.

```
override fun onStart() {
   super.onStart()

   (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = "Título".
}
```

Ou se preferir, pode criar uma função de extensão e chamar dentro do Fragment.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

fun Fragment.setTitle(title: String) {
    (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = title
}
```

Chamada da função de extensão dentro do Fragment.

```
class StartFragment : Fragment() {

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false)
   }

   override fun onStart() {
       super.onStart()

       this.setTitle(getString(R.string.titulo))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NOT_A_PROGRAMMER's answer is right but when you come back to the previous activity or fragment the Title remains the same.

Here is my solution for that.

- Overriding OnPause() or OnStopMethod in the fragment and you can use the same method " ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Your title"); " to set the title of the Activity or Fragment which is present in the backstack.

```
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ((MPOSTransactionActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(//NAME));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for java use

to change the title of the toolbar

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("hello word");

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```