# Using setSupportActionBar() stops hamburger button when opening the navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar, hamburger-menu

I've just begun work on a small little app and would like to change the `Toolbar` title to the name of the fragment the user has selected from the nav drawer, however upon setting the `Toolbar` as the action bar to be able to use :

```
getSupportActionBar.setTitle("[insert category here]")
```

The *toolbar's hamburger button stops opening the nav drawer when clicked*. (You can still open it via dragging in from left).

Does anyone know how to fix this and/or does anyone know of another method to change the toolbar's title? (I found this method via googling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `Activity`:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

And this is for your `Fragment`(you can use it on `OnCreate` or `onResume` method):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    // Set the title 
    ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Your title");
}
```

Also, have a look at:

[Change ActionBar title using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389841/change-actionbar-title-using-fragments)

[Setting Custom ActionBar Title from Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560904/setting-custom-actionbar-title-from-fragment)

Comment: Thankyou - that is a very nice solution that works very well

Answer (score 0):

this worked well with me hope it helps anyone facing the same problem (this fix the problem when you press on the hamburger icon to open the drawerLayout)

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)
//to open the navBar by pressing on the hamburger Icon
ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, binding.drawerLayout,binding.appBarMain.toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
```