# Unable to set title in fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title

I am using the default navigational drawer in Android. I want to change the title of the Action bar depending on the clicked fragment in the drawer. For this I am writing below line in my code:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Coupons");
```

This is returning null object. So I tried using below line of code:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Coupons");
```

This is not able to resolve the method supportActionBar(). The activity is AppCompatActivity.

Comment: You need a listener, you cannot change dynamically like this, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560904/setting-custom-actionbar-title-from-fragment/15561031

Comment: Did you try this getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Coupons");

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389841/change-actionbar-title-using-fragments/38224963

Answer (score 1):

All the titles and strings are placed in strings.xml file in the android studio.
Open strings.xml and change existing text to "Coupons".

strings.xml is placed here in the project view.
[Strings.xml location in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKCQl.png)

Comment: It solved the problem. However, I want to know how programmatically it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

for fragment you can add below code into onCreateView() method

```
getActivity().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: I tried. It is not throwing any error. But it does not change the title!

Comment: did you put it under onCreateView() , it's working fine in my project