# android getSupportActionBar() returns null in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

***UPDATE***

I had not mentioned anything about using [ToolBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) with `ActionBarActivity`. And that is the reason I always get null pointer exception. For those who face same problem [please refere this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29124350/2054829)

---

I have this fragment code to change appearance of support action bar when fragment is changed.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mActionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Dashboard");
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_blue_text)), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getActivity(), "Optima-Regular.ttf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        if( null!= mActionBar){
            mActionBar.setElevation(0);
            mActionBar.setTitle(s);
        }
    }
```

I've referred previous/similar questions regarding how to solve this error. Those solutions suggest to change actionbar appearance in `onActivityCreated()` method. I tried `onAttach()` also. None seems to work. I have used support actionbar to maintain backward compatibility. `Activity` is also casted accordingly to `ActionBarActivity`.

Complete code is pretty much lengthy so I have skipped posting it. If needed I can post complete code and update question with more details as well.

**Error log**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.testapp.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment.onActivityCreated(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:215)
```

Line 215 is : `mActionBar.setElevation(0);`

Comment: What actualy is your problem?

Comment: @hrskrs check the title

Comment: I have added error log also.

Comment: have you imported import android.app.ActionBar or import android.support.v4.app.actionbar?

Comment: @Fahim I have used `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;`

Comment: wrong procedure.why you are creating spannable string in onActivityCreated?you should perform in onCreateView.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for pointing out. Corrected that. But I still get error regarding actionbar being null.

Comment: @Shadow there is no problem in using in onActivityCreated

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/a/18011671/1921263 @Gimali use spannable string and do your stuff and assign in action bar title..

Comment: @Shadow I tried that just now. It doesn't work either. I'm stuck here for long time.

Comment: @Shadow please see the answer I just posted. Apologies if I made you scratch your head just because I have not mentioned more details.

Comment: @Fahim please see the answer I just posted. Apologies if I made you scratch your head just because I have not mentioned more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I missed mentioning little more info in this question. That's the reason other nice SO users could not answer it correctly. So here I answer it my own.

I've used [ToolBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) in place of regular `ActionBar`. When you use `ToolBar` you have to set it as ActionBar. So by doing -

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(toolbarId);
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And after that I can change title and appearance easily by -

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
```

***Just remember to set toolbar as actionbar before actually using actionbar in fragment.***

Comment: I have been looking for this problem for days. Thank you! IT solved my prbolem

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
mActionBar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

or:

```
mActionBar = ((yourActivityName)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

[**UPDATE**]
Remove the line `mActionBar.setElevation(0);` because `setElevation` just available for API 21+

Comment: I tried. It still crashes at null pointer. I'm using `ActionBarActivity` as parent so I have to cast it `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: No need, or cast to your host activity