# ActionBar Title dynamically change with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have 1 Activity with 3 Fragments inside (Home-Login-RestorePass) Initially, HomeFragment shows and the other two are hidden. I want that the ActionBar Title change depending on which Fragment is showing.

I'm trying in my Activity with:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set title
    setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
}
```

and the fragments has the same:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set title
    ((LoginActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.fragment_login));
}
```

But it doesn't work. It always show **R.string.fragment_login** on the title.

I'm using FragmentTransaction for the fragment transition:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentHome);
            LoginFragment loginFragment = (LoginFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentLogin);
            ft.hide(homeFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            ft.show(loginFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

Additionally if i could make appear an Arrow Button (Back) on ActionBar depending of the fragment would be great.

Thanks for your time! Regards.

Comment: Have you considered using `add()`/`remove()` on your `Fragment`s rather than `show()`/`hide()`? Problem looks like it could be due to conflicting calls to change the action bar title, as even hidden `Fragments` are "active", they just lack a UI. Also, the `Fragment` `onResume()` call comes after your `Activity`, and in both `Fragment`s your apparently (going by your code) set the title to `fragment_login`...?

Comment: @PPartisan thanks for your time, i tried with add()/remove() but it doesnt work, the other 2 fragments are over the principal fragment, apparently remove() doesnt take off the fragments from the activity view. All my fragments has its unique setActionBarTitle(*fragmentString*) call. I expressed wrong, sorry. Thank you again :)

Comment: Look this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705242/1770868

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this method in activity to change the `Fragment` and set the title programmatically:

```
private void displayFragment(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = "";
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new Home();
        title = "Home";
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Login();
        title = "Login";
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new RestorePass();
        title = "Restore Password";
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    // update selected fragment and title
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        // change icon to arrow drawable
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow);
    }
}
```

For example, you want Fragment `Home` to be displayed:

```
displayFragment(0);
```

Comment: i f%&(#ing love you =) haha .. with this you solve 3 doubts to me. Thank you, nice weekend.

Answer (score 14):

Keep in mind that if you are using the support Library, you have to specifically cast your Activity when you get it through `getActivity()`. And then you'll want to make sure you are retrieving a support ActionBar by using `getSupportActionBar()`. I was able to set the ActionBar title in my app by using the following code in my Fragment's `onResume()`...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.my_fragment_title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the activity attribute `android:label=""` in the `AndroidManifest` you will be able to set the title post initialisation. I discovered this tracing through the Toolbar source code.