# Set a title for inflated view activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, title, layout-inflater

[My activity screenshot having red highlight area where i want to set title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYRJ3.jpg)

I inflated a view in my activity.I want to set a title for it, `setTitle` and `label` tag in manifest is not working i have tried like thousand times.
How to set title in highlighted area of screenshot my code for this is below

```
 FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameHome);
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View inflate = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, true);
 frameLayout.addView(inflate);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Comment: you can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560904/setting-custom-actionbar-title-from-fragment

Comment: thnx **stanislav-bondar** **vishnu-kumar-singhvi** i got my answer.Apprecting your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a title at the right corner of your app bar, you can put a `TextView` in the `Toolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Your Title"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Add this `Toolbar` in your `Activity` layout at the top: `activity_main.xml`

Comment: its not adding what i wanted. it just add a textview below the toolbar @bob

Comment: You should use this toolbar as your app bar/ action bar. Use this as your parent theme: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. And set that toolbar as action bar.

Comment: thnx @bob  i got my answer.Apprecting your effort